# Insert data in database from the form using onetomany also insert multiple seatNo in row according to selected value

Tags: java, html, spring

I need to insert data from the form in database..also using onetomany mapping             so i can insert multiple row values of the bus seatno. The user should be able to choose the total seat number from the dropdown box of addbus.jsp and according to the selected value data should be inserted in the sideA table. if the user chooses no 4 in the dropdown option then in the sideA table 1,2,3 and 4 value should be inserted in seatNo column in different row

> Bus.java

```
package edu.abc.test.models;    
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "addbus")
public class Bus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Bus_ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Bus_No")
    private String busNo;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "bus_ID")
    private List<SideA> sideA;  
    /*Getters and setters*/
  }
```

> SideA.java

```
package edu.abc.test.models;    
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "sideA")
public class SideA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "sideA_ID")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bus_ID", insertable = false,  updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private Bus bus;
    @Column(name = "Seat_No")
    private int seatNo;
    @Column(name = "Status",columnDefinition = "enum('Available','Taken')             default 'Available'")
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.Available;
    /*Getter and setters*/
    public enum Status{
        Available,
        Taken
    }
}
```

> BusController.java

```
package edu.abc.test;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import edu.abc.test.daos.BusDao;
import edu.abc.test.models.Bus;

@Controller
public class BusController {
    //private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BusController.class);

    @Autowired
    private BusDao busDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "adBus",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addBus(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("bus",new Bus());
        return "addBus";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "adBus", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insert(@ModelAttribute Bus bus,Model model){
        busDao.insert(bus);
        model.addAttribute("bus",new Bus());
        return "addBus";
    }
}
```

> BusDao.java

```
package edu.abc.test.daos;    
import java.util.List;    
import edu.abc.test.models.Bus;    

public interface BusDao {
    public Long insert(Bus bus);
    public List<Bus>getAll();
    public Bus get(Long id);
}

BusDaoImpl.java

package edu.abc.test.daos;    
import java.util.List;    
import javax.annotation.Resource;    
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import edu.abc.test.models.Bus;

@Repository
public class BusDaoImpl implements BusDao{
    @Resource
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Long insert(Bus bus) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Long id = (Long) session.save(bus);
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Bus> getAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Bus.class);
        List<Bus> busList = criteria.list();
        return busList;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Bus get(Long id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Bus bus = (Bus) session.get(Bus.class, id);
        return bus;
    }

}
```

> addBus.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Bus</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "body">
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="bus">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan ="2"><h2>Add Bus</h2></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <form:label path="busNo">Bus No</form:label> </td>
                <td> <form:input path="busNo"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <form:label path="sideA.seatNo">Side A1</form:label> </td>
                <td> <form:select path="sideA.seatNo">
                        <form:option value="6">6</form:option>  
                        <form:option value="10">10</form:option>    
                        <form:option value="12">12</form:option>    
                        <form:option value="14">14</form:option>
                        <form:option value="16">16</form:option>        
                     </form:select> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value = "Save"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```